# how to solve this route error: "Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am adding a new contactUs page in my project which is having a form data to store to the mongoDB collection. But when i set all the controller and route files and run the app i am getting this error. I am not getting how to solve this error. I have made sure all the files' names are fine

My different code files are as following

My express.js file

```
import path from 'path'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'
import compress from 'compression'
import cors from 'cors'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import Template from './../template'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.routes'
import authRoutes from './routes/auth.routes'
import shopRoutes from './routes/shop.routes'
import productRoutes from './routes/product.routes'
import orderRoutes from './routes/order.routes'
import contactUsRoutes from './routes/contactUs.routes'

// modules for server side rendering
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import MainRouter from './../client/MainRouter'
import StaticRouter from 'react-router-dom/StaticRouter'

import { SheetsRegistry } from 'react-jss/lib/jss'
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider'
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, createGenerateClassName } from 'material-ui/styles'
import { blueGrey, lightGreen } from 'material-ui/colors'
//end

//comment out before building for production
import devBundle from './devBundle'

const CURRENT_WORKING_DIR = process.cwd()
const app = express()

//comment out before building for production
devBundle.compile(app)

// parse body params and attache them to req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(compress())
// secure apps by setting various HTTP headers
app.use(helmet())
// enable CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing
app.use(cors())

app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, 'dist')))

// mount routes
app.use('/', userRoutes)
app.use('/', authRoutes)
app.use('/', shopRoutes)
app.use('/', productRoutes)
app.use('/', orderRoutes)
app.use('/', contactUsRoutes)

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry()
   const theme = createMuiTheme({
     palette: {
       primary: {
       light: '#21d192',
       main: '#1cb77f',
       dark: '#1cb77f',
       contrastText: '#fff',
     },
     secondary: {
        light: '#21d192',
        main: '#1cb77f',
        dark: '#1cb77f',
       contrastText: '#000',
     },
       openTitle: blueGrey['400'],
       protectedTitle: lightGreen['400'],
       type: 'light'
     }
   })
   const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName()
   const context = {}
   const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
         <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={new Map()}>
              <MainRouter/>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
         </JssProvider>
      </StaticRouter>
     )
    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(303, context.url)
    }
    const css = sheetsRegistry.toString()
    res.status(200).send(Template({
      markup: markup,
      css: css
    }))
})

// Catch unauthorised errors
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
    res.status(401).json({"error" : err.name + ": " + err.message})
  }
})

export default app
```

contactUs.routes.js file

```
import contactUsCtrl from '../controllers/contactUs.controller'

const router = express.Router()

router.route('/api/contact/')
  .post(contactUsCtrl.create)

router.param('contactUsId', contactUsCtrl.contactUsByID)

export default router
```

contactUs.controller.js file

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import errorHandler from '../helpers/dbErrorHandler'


const create = (req, res, next) => {
    const contact = new Contact(req.body)
    contact.save((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        })
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "You Complained Successfully!"
      })
    })
  }
  export default create
```

api-contact.js file

```
    return fetch('/api/contact/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(contact)
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
export {create}
```

Help me out please.I am not getting what have gone wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contactUs.controller.js` doesn‘t have an export named `create`, only a default export.

### Either change

`const create = ...` to 
`export const create = ...` in *contactUs.controller.js*

### or change

`router.route('/api/contact/').post(contactUsCtrl.create)`
to
`router.route('/api/contact/').post(contactUsCtrl)` in *contactUs.routes.js*